# udev symbolic links - where is /dev/sda pointing to

Tags: linux, centos, udev

It is said that udev create symbolic links identifying the actual device and /dev/disk/by-uuid is an example.

> [root@centos1 by-uuid]# pwd
>
> /dev/disk/by-uuid
>
> [root@centos1 by-uuid]# ls -l
>
> total 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 26 00:59 4cfc879d-1d4e-4289-856c-5f532a74bb2d -> ../../sda

Does the above means that
a) /dev/sda is pointing to uuid 4cfc879d-1d4e-4289-856c-5f532a74bb2d

or

b) uuid 4cfc879d-1d4e-4289-856c-5f532a74bb2d is pointing to /dev/sda ?

==================================================

If the answer is a, i always thought that link are suppose to be from left to right ?  and how will someone reference the uuid to go to /dev/sda ?
Also i thought /dev/sda is suppose to be dynamically added by udev and its naming is base on some rules.

If the answer is b, then where is sda pointing to ? It is said that the kernel add devices to the /dev/ folder dynamically and with udev we can persist of the naming of the devices in it.

> [root@centos1 dev]# pwd
>
> /dev
>
> [root@centos1 dev]# ls -lt *sda*
>
> brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Jun 26 00:59 sda

==================================================

I tried to find the rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/ but to no avail.
I am on CentOS.

I am trying at /lib/udev/rules.d/, but can't see the rules that add sda into /dev/

Please advise.

Comment: Please see my Edit 2. I think now you have all the info you need.

Answer (score 4):

The link is *to* /dev/sda1. you can establish that with the *file* command: in my system, for instance,

```
  # file *
  ff28e743-4409-41b3-99ea-f133cdcc86be: symbolic link to `../../sda1'
```

Thus, your option *b* is right. /dev/sda is **not** a link, hence it does not point to anything else at all: it is just a special (device) file, see for instance [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types#Device_file).

I do not use CentOS, but in my Debian/Kubuntu systems the disk rules are located in */lib/udev/rules.d*, under

```
   # ls -lh 60-per*
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  616 apr 15 22:33 60-persistent-alsa.rules
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2,5K apr 15 22:33 60-persistent-input.rules
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  947 apr 15 22:33 60-persistent-serial.rules
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  929 mag  4  2012 60-persistent-storage-dm.rules
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5,6K apr 15 22:33 60-persistent-storage.rules
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1,4K apr 15 22:33 60-persistent-storage-tape.rules
     -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  769 apr 15 22:33 60-persistent-v4l.rules
```

The relevant file, of course, is *60-persistent-storage.rules*. If you cannot locate it here in your system, I suggest you try:

```
    find / -type f -name '*persistent-storage*.rules'
```

Edit:

> is /sda added in /dev by udev then ?

Yes.

> how do we ensure "sda" will always remain as "sda" ?

We do not. The rule is automatically generated by *udev* at installation time. In fact, the above-mentioned file contains the following rule:

```
   # scsi devices
   KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}!="?*", IMPORT{program}="scsi_id --export --whitelisted -d $devnode", ENV{ID_BUS}="scsi"
```

**EDIT 2**

The simplest thing, given that you cannot make up your mind, is to set up your own rules. Suppose you have a device, called *now* sdd, but you want to call it sda at next reboot.

First you need to find out some parameters:

```
   udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdd)
```

This will spit out a lot of info. Search for lines such as these (yours will be different, of course):

```
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="18a5"
  ATTRS{idProduct}=="0302"
  ATTRS{serial}=="TT0E4E008XW3DT9H"
```

You can now use these paramaters to craft your own rule, to be inserted into */etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules*:

```
 ATTRS{idVendor}=="18a5", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0302", ATTRS{serial}=="TT0E4E008XW3DT9H", KERNEL=="sd?", NAME="sda", RUN+="/home/my_name/bin/my_program"
```

The last part, *RUN+="/home/my_name/bin/my_program"*, is optional: you can use it to run a command, if you wish to, but you may omit it altogether.

Comment: is /sda added in /dev by udev then ? how do we ensure the disk refererenced to by "sda" will always remain as "sda" ?

Comment: @Noob Pls see my edit.

Comment: thank you for your clear explanation.  I am not really sure of the syntaxes use in the rules - but with the rule that is shown above, does it make sure that "sda" will remain as "sda"  then ? could it happen that 1 day, i take out the disk which is assigned "sda" , and plug back it another day and got assigned "sdb" instead ?

Comment: why can't i @ to MariusMatutiae ?

Comment: @Noob Because you are replying to my answer, so it comes to me automatically

Comment: Yes, you can be sure that  that disk will always be sda, even though this applies only to permanent storage, not to removable disks, be they USB or SATA. The reason is that removable disks cannot be known a priori (or at installation!), hence there is no way to establish a consistent naming scheme. For removable disks, it is you who has to provide a naming scheme, if you wish to have a  static set of name assignments.

Comment: Marius if i have disk1 and disk2 assigned sda and sdb, if i swap their physical location, will disk1 still be "sda" and disk2 "sdb" ?  i am formatting an entire device (not partition) to a ext4 fllesystem and have mounted it on 1 mountpoint /u03/.    (using /dev/sdb  /u03/ ext4 defaults 1 3).

Comment: @Noob  What type of disks are they? Removable or not?

Comment: there are 2 servers. 1 is a desktop type with normal sata disk. removalable yes, but not hotpluggable. Another is a rackmount  server with sas disk. removal yes, hotpluggable yes.  What i would like to know is the underlying concept if udev name device randomly and would use certain rules to establish naming. if we are able to get pass the rule (e.g. swapping the disk connected to the sata connector), then the device naming to previously tied device will not be accurate - am i right ?

Comment: for the rackmount, it is hogpluggable, but still need to restart OS to see the disk though.

Comment: thank you for the wonderful example and sorry for the late reply.  With your new edit, does that mean that even for internal disks, the detection and naming of the devices by udev in the /dev/ is still random to a certain extend (e.g. depending on the order that the disks get detected) , so by changing their physical position, i might/cound get a different naming compared to prior change

Comment: are you still around ? are you able to elaborate further on why udev is not able to provide persistent naming by default ?

Comment: @Noob Not what I said. udev can do that. I only provided you with an alternative way to set your heart at rest.

Comment: are you able to shed some light on this "The kernel detects devices asynchronously, udev mirrors the kernel's sysfs filesystem and so the devices are named and numbered in order of detection. So by default udev provides no persistent device names."  https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Udev

I understand that udev can base on rules to provide persistent naming. But i am not sure why if as according to what the link say (kernel detect devices asynchronously) then how come internal disks is not subjected to naming changes ?